# Electronic Length Measurement

Tags: sensor

I need to measure small distances (from 0-5mm) with precision upto 3 decimal places (like a micrometer). What sort of sensor can I use for this?

This is for measuring terminal heights. I understand that there are dedicated micrometers for this purpose but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it electronically.

Comment: Not worth an answer but capacitive sensing can be quite accurate for ranges 0-10mm. Also somewhat difficult to implement. Can't say what is "better" without knowing your requirements.

Comment: Does it have to be contactless? Are there any metallic surfaces involved?

Comment: Not necessary for it to be contact less. Yes, metallic surfaces are involved.

Comment: Any idea what is the working principle of those 'touch micrometer' (mentioned by original poster) at 1 to 10 micro meter resolution? What resolution can highly refined LVDT do?

Answer (score 9):

Check out [LDC1000](http://www.ti.com/product/ldc1000). It is inductance (not inductive) sensor IC, it only need external coil and capacitor to do 24-bit measurements in broad frequency range.

Edit: If this was a site about industrial automation, i would recommend to get a LVDT. But it is not.

Comment: It's a nice chip this one +1

Comment: Just cause it's used in industrial automation, doesn't mean an lvdt doesn't belong here :) +1 Also, that's a neat IC! Now I have to find a reason to use it!

Comment: @venny this is a nice chip but the issue is that the object's thickness that I have to measure is also conductive. I don't think this would work there.

Comment: The object, a wire terminal, whose thickness I have to measure after it is crimped, is also conductive. So I don't think this IC would work.

Comment: @Saad Wire terminals of ordinary size are too small for this method. You would have to employ some lever mechanism.

Comment: @venny Actually, I had an idea. I can print this inductive pattern on a PCB, which can be moved/slided, and then have a fixed metal plate. The slider can then move and come to a stop when it touches the crimp. The distance between the metal plate and the PCB pattern will be the same as the height of the crimp... this should work unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a pair of digital calipers for about $15-20 and interface with the chip.

[image]

Interfacing with the chip is fairly straightforward and you can find examples on the net. Virtually all of the Chinese made calipers have a similar interface- a 1.5V serial stream of data. Famous Japanese brands such as Mitutoyo use a somewhat different scheme.

Internally these devices use a periodic pattern on a PCB substrate and a capacitive sensing scheme (originally developed by a Swiss company). They are not absolute measurement devices so you have to be able to zero them.

Answer (score 2):

Among other brands, [this](http://www.ia.omron.com/products/family/3120/specification.html) is one of many examples may be meeting your requirement, one factor is optical property of the pin to be measured. May be best to test a loaner unit before committed buy.

Mechanic touching sensor (caliper or the likes) is more tolerance to different type of objects. Optical can be more accurate, faster if it 'matches' the object property.

Dedicated micrometers or 'refined' caliper may be simple and better, but, since original poster ask for alternatives, optical worth trying out because if it 'matches' the object, it is higher accuracy, faster and clean (non touching).

You can buy off-the-shelf or if you want to design and make it yourself, the working principle is optical microscope with moving focusing. Focusing (as in turning the manual focus knob on traditional high-school microscope) is measured distance, but in highly refined version.

ZW-S30, measurement distance (sensor to object) is 27 to 33 mm, resolution 0.25 micro meter

This contacted type, from another brand, is 1 micro meter accuracy too. Does anyone know if its working principle is LDVT or like the above caliper?

[image: another brand contacted device]

Comment: The Keyence product is a kind of absolute optical 'glass' scale system.